# Approval process step field update doesn't appear in same step's Visualforce email template?

Tags: email-template, approval-process, field-update, merge-field

1. Two step approval process on custom object `Foo__c`
2. initial value of `Foo__c.Status__c` is 'Submitted'

Approval Step 1 actions are threefold:

1. Field update on `Foo__c.status__c` = 'Step 1 approved'
2. Text email alert to recipient list with text body of: `Status:  {!Foo__c.status__c}`
3. VF email alert as shown below:

   ```
   <messaging:emailTemplate subject="some subject" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Foo__c">
     <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
       <html>
         <apex:outputText value="Status:"/>
         <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Status__c}"/>
       </html>
     </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
     <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
        Status: {!Foo__c.status__c}
     </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
   </messaging:emailTemplate>
   ```

Although SFDC doc says that Field Updates execute before Email Alerts in a Workflow, I get the following results:

- Email sent to next step (2) in approval process, email template includes Status = 'Step 1 Approved' [expected result]
- Text-based email sent to recipient with Status = 'Step 1 Approved' [expected result]
- VF email sent to recipient with Status = 'Submitted' **[?!? not expected result]**

I don't get it.

- Why would the text-based email emitted in Approval Process Step 1 action contain the new (and correct) Field Update value but the VF-based email emitted in the exact same Approval Process Step 1 action does not have the new value?
- It is as if SFDC sends off the VF-based email before the field update has processed contrary to expectations.

Comment: Reproduced by SFDC developer support in their own org; their remark: `...It is really weird behavior and I am escalating this to backline engineers to get resolution.`

Comment: SFDC engineering acks the issue, SFDC support says: "As of now we are not sure whether it is a WAD or known issue with salesforce, if WAD then the document http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&language=en_US must be corrected."

Comment: Workaround suggested by SFDC support (but not yet tried by me): `In approval process, rather than using an email alert, create a workflow rule on Status update (ex: when status equals 'Approved-step1') and create a workflow action to send an email alert(using VF template). Important thing is, you need to select 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change' on field update under approval process.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFDC developer support confirms that if you do a field update in an Approval Process step action and also have a VF (not text/HTML) email alert in the same approval process step action, that VF email alert will NOT merge in the `updated-from-the-Field-Update` value into the VF template. This is contrary to the doc which states that field updates occur prior to email alerts.

Note that text/html email alerts will merge in the `updated-from-the-Field-Update` value into the generated email.

The workaround, which I confirmed, is to:

1. Change the field update in the approval process step to 're-evaluate workflow after update' and
2. Remove the email alert from the approval process step's action list and
3. Create a normal workflow on your target SObject that tests for the value of the field update in #1 and includes an email alert for your VF email template.

Note that if you do a field update in step *i* of an approval process, the new value of the field WILL BE available to the email sent to the approvers in step *i+1*.  It is only **intrastep** VF email alerts that don't get the new value of that step's field updates.

If SFDC support notifies me that this is working-as-designed, expect a doc update; if it is a bug, expect it to appear on Known Issues.

> Update - SFDC R&D says this is working as designed -- here is their explanation:
>
> R&D explanation:
>
> ########## CAUSE: The VF template queries the database to retrieve the field data, but the TEXT/HTML template shares the Entity > Object (Java) from the Workflow to merge the field data.
>
> SOLUTION/WORKAROUND:
>
> ############## customer has 2 solutions here.
>
> Either 1)Customer can use TEXT/HTML email template instead of VF template in approval
>   process OR 
>   2) Remove email alert(which uses VF template) from approval
>   process and implement the workflow action to send an email alert(with
>   VF template) when the status field changes. Need to select
>   'Re-evaluate Work flow Rules after Field Change' on field update under
>   approval process.

Personally, I think this explanation needs to be added to the doc as it is counter-intuitive to think that VF email templates associated with WF alerts won't behave the same as text/HTML email templates with the same WF alert.